# Highcharts dynamic x axis timestamp issue

Tags: highcharts, timestamp

Hello I have a dynamic spline in highcharts.

I setup it

```
 type: 'linear',
 tickPixelInterval: 100,
```

`x = x + 10` adding next point.

So 10    20    30    40   ..... keeping   1200 1300

Now I want to show this linear number to time stamp. and Found out some javescript converter.
But It works incorrectly.

What should I changed it.

```
00:00:10
00:00:20
...
00:12:00
```

this format I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you change type of xAxis to datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp in Highcharts needs in milliseconds

to get 00:00:10

its timestamp is 10 * 1000 = 10000

so increment the timestamp every time by 10000 milliseconds rather than 10

Hope this will be useful

Comment: + 10 is collect way to add new point. I want to show the x-axis for timestamp format.

Comment: This is what I use. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update
and I want to start 0 and add 10 secs. It might help you understood.